# Run a subprocess in python and both show the output in "real time" and save it to a variable

Tags: python, subprocess

I would like to be able to run a subprocess from python code and both see the output in real time and once the process is finished have the output in a variable

Right now I do one of either two things

1) Run subprocess using subprocess.call in that case I get the output in real time but I don't have at the end the output in a variable (I want to parse it and extract values from it)

2) Run subprocess using subprocess.check_output in that case I have the output in a variable but if I want to see it then I have to print it "manually"

Is there a way to get both things "together" ?

Hope it is clear, I can add my code if you need

Thanks !!!

EDIT:

This is my current code

[image]

I added a timeout optional parameter (Default value is 1200 and also deal with shell (For some reason same commands that work in Linux do not work in Windows if I don't have the shell=True) the "mode" parameter is the one that I use to differentiate the cases where I want the output in "real time" and I don't have to parse it and the other cases

I was wondering if there is a cleaner and better way to achieve same results

Comment: do you have any code that's not working or have you tried anything yet?

Comment: My code is working but I want to know if there is a better way to do this, right now I do something like this

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are trying to run some command `your_command` You can use the following:

```
some_proc = subprocess.Popen(['your_command'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` does stdout the result on success. Afterwards, you can access the output as follows:

```
store_in_var = some_proc.stdout
```

Now you can parse your `store_in_var`

Answer (score -1):

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE

comd = input('command here : ')
comds = comd.split(' ')
f = subprocess.run(comds, shell= True,stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
result = f.stdout.decode()
errors = f.stderr.decode()
```