# Get shell output in real-time and store all output in a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, shell, subprocess

I'm looking for a simple way to run a shell command in python 3, get its output in real-time and finally store all output to a variable.

I searched the web for a possible solution but couldn't find one.
I also found a similar question on [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55040507/run-a-subprocess-in-python-and-both-show-the-output-in-real-time-and-save-it-t), but no one provided a clear answer. 
I end up with this code, but it's more of a workaround then a clear solution

```
def get_os_cmd(command):

 proc_file = '/tmp/proc.tmp'

 if os.path.isfile(proc_file):
     os.remove(proc_file)  # remove temporary file

 proc = subprocess.Popen(
    command,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    shell=True, encoding='utf-8')

 with open(proc_file, 'a+') as f:
     for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, ''):
         string = line.rstrip()
         print(string)
         f.write(f'{string}\n')
 return proc.stdout, proc.returncode
```

Comment: I had this problem a year ago, although I need to examine the stdout stream in real time.  What you posted is essentially what I'm still using.

Comment: This code writes the output to a file, is that your desired result? When you say "store all output to a variable" do you mean a variable in python or an environment variable in your shell? What is the reason for running this in python rather than a shell such as bash? ie 'command > /tmp/proc.tmp'

Comment: I write it to a file because I didn't find a way to store the output to a variable.
The function which calls a shell command is a part of a bigger script that does other things among this function. that's why I cannot run it straight in the shell.

Answer (score 0):

doki.al
This program is good and will work good enough i think.

```
import os
command = ['dir', 'echo program working']
for i in command:
    stream = os.popen(i)    # Execute the command in command list
    output = stream.read()  # Read the output of the executed program
    print(output)           # Print the output
```

This program first executes a command in cmd and then reads it and displays it.

This program returns the variable output as a string.
If you want a list you can use

```
output = stream.readline()
```

This will include all the newlines.
I hope this solves your problem. If not feel free to get back in comment section.